# Unable to attach attachment while sending mail

Tags: perl

Can anyone please help with attaching two text files while sending email using Email::Simple. I am able to receive mail but without the attachments

I have tried a lot but couldn't make it work, not sure if I am having the incorrect modules. I did not want to use MIME::Lite because of the recommendation by the creator of MIME::Lite. I basically wanted to use my own SMTP details, and got Email::Sender as recommendation. Everything works except the attachment.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Email::Sender::Simple qw(sendmail);
use Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP ();
use Email::Simple ();
use Email::Simple::Creator ();
use Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP::TLS;
use Email::MIME;
use IO::All;

my $transport = Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP::TLS->new({
    host => 'smtp.office365.com',
    port => 587,
    sasl_username => 'abcsender@abc.com',
    sasl_password => 'P@ssw0rd@123',
    username => 'abcsender@abc.com',
    password => 'P@ssw0rd@123'
});

my @parts = (
        Email::MIME->create(
                attributes => {
                        content_type => "text/plain",
                        filename     => "/tmp/ERROR1493720941.log",
                        charset      => "US-ASCII",
                        disposition     =>"attachment",
                },    
                body => io( "/tmp/ERROR1493720941.log" )->all,
        ),
        Email::MIME->create(
                attributes => {
                        content_type => "text/plain",
                        filename     => "/tmp/FAILED1493720941.log",
                        charset      => "US-ASCII",
                        disposition     =>"attachment",
                },    
                body => io( "/tmp/FAILED1493720941.log" )->all,
        ),
);

my $email = Email::Simple->create(
  header => [
    To      => 'gsrivastava@abc.com',
    From    => 'abcsender@abc.com',
    Subject => 'Hi!',
  ],
  body => "Hello",
  parts      => [ @parts ],
);

sendmail($email, { transport => $transport });
```

As asked by @DaveCross in comment, here is the output of $email->as_string

```
$VAR1 = 'To: gsrivastava@abc.com^M
From: abcsender@abc.com^M
Subject: Hi!^M
Date: Sun, 7 May 2017 07:58:46 -0400^M
^M
Hello^M
```

Comment: What do you see if you print `$email->as_string` just before you send the mail?

Comment: @DaveCross $VAR1 = 'To: gsrivastava@abc.com^M
From: abcsender@abc.com^M
Subject: Hi!^M
Date: Sun, 7 May 2017 07:58:46 -0400^M
^M
Hello^M
';

Comment: Please add that to your question. It's largely unreadable in a comment.

Comment: @DaveCross I have updated this in the question

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this is a pretty simple mistake to make. You are creating a MIME email, but when you get to creating the actual email object, you use this code:

```
my $email = Email::Simple->create(
  header => [
    To      => 'gsrivastava@abc.com',
    From    => 'abcsender@abc.com',
    Subject => 'Hi!',
  ],
  body => "Hello",
  parts      => [ @parts ],
);
```

Email::Simple isn't intended for MIME mail messages, so it doesn't understand the `parts` attribute and ignores it. To create a MIME email, you need to use Email::MIME.

```
my $email = Email::MIME->create(
  header => [
    To      => 'gsrivastava@abc.com',
    From    => 'abcsender@abc.com',
    Subject => 'Hi!',
  ],
  parts      => [ @parts ],
);
```

Note that I've removed the `body` attribute. MIME emails can't have both parts and a body. The solution is to add another element to `@parts` that contains your body text.

```
my @parts = (
        Email::MIME->create(
                attributes => {
                        content_type => 'text/plain',
                        disposition  => 'attachment',
                        charset      => 'US-ASCII',
                        encoding     => 'quoted-printable',
                },
                body_str => 'Hello',
        ),

        ...
);
```